# Global variables issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have read the article [Global Variables Are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and i have some question:

Supposed i have several variables for example:

```
int loops
```

This variable should be accessible from anywhere in the code so i have 2 options:

1. define this variable as global inside my main form
2. define class:

> ```
> public static class Loops 
> {
>     public static int loops {get; set;} 
> }
> ```

What's the right way to do it and what is the differences between the both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public static variable inside a static class is like your old global variable. The only difference is that you always need to specify the class name to access its value. It is available in every part of your code that has a reference to the assembly and namespace where that static class is contained. And there is just one value for that variable.

A public instance variable inside a form is a variable that exists only if you build an instance of your form and it is a different variable from any other variable in other instances of the same form

for example

```
public static class GlobalAppVariables 
{ 
   public static int loops {get; set;} 
   ......
}
```

in othe part of your project or other assemblies with correct reference to the defining assembly

```
for(int x = 0; x < GlobalAppVariables.loops; x++)
```

instead with a global public variable inside a form class

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
   public int loops {get; set;}
}
```

to use that variable you need an instance of the MyForm class, and if you have two instances, you have two different variables.

```
MyForm f = new MyForm();
f.loops = 15;
for(int x = 0; x < f.loops; x++)
    ......

MyForm f1 = new MyForm();
f1.loops = 100;
.....
```

From an OOP point of view, and for every non trivial programs you should try hard to avoid global variables. But that's is theory, in real world with real constraints (performance, time to develop, programmer expertise, nature of the task and other considerations) it is not always possible to  completely avoid them.

My suggestion is to confine them in a well understood class with explicit property backing fields to allow the maximum of flexibility in case of future changes. Of course, documentation plays a key role here

Comment: So what your recommendation ? inside new class or in my form ? the problem is that i have several variables (approximately 15) so it's become ugly for my opinion to use all this variables as global inside my form

Comment: As I have said in the updated answer, it depends. If you don't need them outside the form, then make them global inside the form, but not public. If they are not strictly related to you form code then a global class is preferable. Also it depend on how do you engineer your code. Usually a separation of concerns between the user interface and the underlying logic is mandatory. Having a form that should share some variable smell fishy from where I stand, but I don't know your business.

Comment: why don't you add application configuration file?

Comment: @Andrew of course a configuration file could be a solution, but again, it depends on the context that we know very little about. Configuration files are the way to go when these 'globals' represents working parameters of your code. Sometimes, instead, you don't want anyone to mess with 'global things' So... it is a complicated world.

Comment: Right you are. BTW loops doen't need to be instance variable of MainForm class, it can be public static. Then the technical problem is with cyclic references Form-Logic-Form and the conceptual - encapsulation of things.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a project with business logic, UI layer will consume it and have a reference to it. If you business logic is dependent on `loops` in your form class then not only won't you be able to add a cyclic reference but it is not a good idea for BL to be directly dependent on UI, if we talk about OOP here.

Second option is good enough if you keep all configurations in your, say, `Configuration` class, but changing it means recompiling the solution.

`Application Configuration File` is the right way to go for application configurations:

- Add an Application Configuration File item to your project (right click project > add item). This will create a file called app.config in your project.
- Edit the file by adding entries like `<add key="loops" value="10" />` within the `<appSettings>` tag.
- Add a reference to the System.Configuration dll in your project, and reference the `loops` setting in the config using `ConfigurationManager` 
  like:

  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loops"]`

Answer (score 0):

It depends my friend, seems that for your first option its not global if you want to be used every where in the form, in such a case the form becomes your context. While using a static variable within a class (public and NOT Nested class) is truly a global variable that should be used carefully and has a good purpose to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The article you referenced applies to C++. In C++ a global variable is a variable that is declared outside of a class. In C#, however, a global variable is a variable declared public inside of a class (as a variable cannot exist outside of a class or a struct). The equivalent of avoiding these global variables would be to declare them as properties with appropriate scope applied to the `get` and `set` accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a global variable does not respect any of the base priciples of OOP; the whole program can read it and maybe modify it( unless that is what you want ). The solution is to make a class with `private static int loops {get; set;}`